# KSQL stream to S3 bucket with node-red

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, node-red, ksqldb

In nodered,I have been able to subscribe `json stream` ABC using `KSQL node`. Now I am trying to push that stream to S3 bucket in form of json file with `kafka-s3-connector` but i am able to do this with cli only,not with using `SQL and S3 node` installed in Node-Red.Is there something additional node missing in it,kindly help regarding the same?

Comment: Please provide more information about the exact node modules you have tried (there are many SQL nodes available). Also, what does your flow look like, and what errors do you see in the debug sidebar and/or console logs?

Answer (score 0):

> i am able to do this with cli only

I am not familiar with NodeRED, but you can send an HTTP POST request into a Kafka Connect Distributed Server with [S3 Connector](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-s3/) available

```
curl -XPOST http://connect-server:8083/connectors \
-d '{
  "name": "sink-s3",
  "config": {
    "topics": "your_topic",
    "tasks.max": "2",

    "name": "sink-s3",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",

    "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",

    "s3.bucket.name": "example-kafka-bucket",

    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",

     "__comment": "Confluent Kafka Connect properties",
    "flush.size": "200",
    "s3.part.size": "5242880",
    "schema.generator.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
    "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
    "schema.compatibility": "BACKWARD"
  }
}'
```